# Please explain this soviet proof of why sqrt(2) is irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof, irrational-numbers

[Proof by Contradiction in a Soviet Analysis Textbook by Fikhtengolts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ3VG.png)

I don't follow the steps from since $p = 2*q^2$. Typo? So then why or how exactly is q ODD? That step was not logical to me.

Whereas this proof makes sense -> http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/q1.html

Comment: "$p$ and $q$ have no common factors"

Comment: Since $p$ is even, and $p$ and $q$ have no common factors, $q$ cannot also be even.

Comment: If $q$, as well as $p$ were even, $p$ and $q$ would have the common factor $2$, contrary to the assumption that${p\over q}$ is irreducible.

Comment: Ok I just thought it was ridiculous for there to be a typo on the first page. Still don't see why q must be necessarily ODD if p and q are taken to be coprime

Comment: @Quesop If they are coprime then they have no common factors. Is $2$ not a common factor if they are both even?

Comment: Obviously, that equation is a typographic error, it should read $p^2=2q^2$, as implied from the previous defining equation $(p/q)^2=2$. Does that help your understanding?

Comment: Both proofs are just one and the same, taking into account the typographical error in Fikhtengolts book...which, imo, is one of the best Analysis books ever.